# How to use Type Model on Firestore Function to get Field Value

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm getting my data from firestore and I can print doc.data and it gives me an object with the list of values from the collection, one of which is unixtime.

Problem: I can't print only the specific value of unixtime, it comes through as undefined so I'm trying to figure out how to apply my type model correctly so I can console log the value of unixtime.  What am I doing wrong with my type model implementation? How do I print only the value of unixtime? 1st photo is the data in firestore, 2nd photo is doc.data printing in console.log cloud function. 3rd photo is if I add myVar2 to the end of doc.data, it says "doc.data undefined".

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';

export default async () => {
  const FirestoreInstance = firestore();
  const getunixtime = FirestoreInstance.collection('2023WNS').doc('uDIP3FvGg2bxDbBusJ9cq4iIyec2');
  const doc = await getunixtime.get();

  type ObjectKey2 = keyof typeof doc.data;
  const myVar2 = 'unixtime' as ObjectKey2;

  if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log('No such document!');
  } else {
    console.log('Document data:', doc.data[myVar2]);
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

This show's changes suggested in comment below.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to show the contents of the document that your code is reading.  We can't see your database.  I'll say that TypeScript types almost certainly has nothing to do with this.  If you print the contents of the document data and a field isn't there, then it certainly just isn't in the document at all.  Changing the type won't change that result.  TypeScript types are just suggestions for what's in a document, not enforcements.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, okay so I updated it with photos. It definitely is in the data as it's logged in cloud console. It's typescript as in it's a typescript function, it's sent through node.js as a cloud function, it's a file type of .ts. Hope this clarifies my situation. Thanks.

Comment: unixtime has a value in your screenshot.  Why do you say it's undefined?  It's not clear what the problem is and how we can reproduce it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Okay, I changed the code to show what I was doing. I'm trying to make unixtime a variable by itself, when it logs like this it shows doc.data undefined, the error is in the 3rd photo. Hope this clears things up and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[doc.data()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot#documentsnapshotdata) is a function that returns an object, not a property.  All you need to do is this:

```
const data = doc.data();
const unixtime = data.unixtime;
```

This has nothing to do with TypeScript or typing information.  You're just not calling the data method to get the document data.

Comment: Okay I think we're on the same page, but when I enter this code it shows "data is possibly undefined" I posted a screenshot above for how I tried to implement it. So close but what am I doing wrong?  Thanks a million.

Comment: That's a completely unrelated issue. You should just check to see if data is undefined before using it, or use the `!!` operator to force skip that requirement.  That's a standard TypeScript warning.  If you click the link I provided for the doc.data() api docs, you'll see that the definition of the function says that it can return undefined if the document you requested doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry but I am new to running js/ts firestore functions, everything I know is from flutter so bear with me when I ask where would I use the !! operator or how I would implement the check to see if the data is undefined? I understand what you are saying, but I don't understand how to implement. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay so I got it to work by just adding a single ! to data, similar to how it works in flutter, don't understand if a second ! is needed but nonetheless it works, thanks for your patience.